# How can I make a daemon cache a server response?

Tags: php, daemon

I have a daemon script running in PHP. This script continuously hits an endpoint and gets the response from a resource and checks for a response.

The response is typically

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "status" : "true"}
```

most of the time.

Occasionally, it could turn out that the response might change to

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "status" : "false"}
```

I have logic to read values of a, b and c and perform operations based on them.

My question is, is there a way to somehow cache this response instead of hitting the end point over and over at the daemon level?

Or is there a way to cache the json response from the server level?

Comment: so you cache it locally, then how do you know when it changes with out checking ?

Answer (score 0):

Use each element of your object as an array key:

```
$responses[$a][$b][$c]['status'] = true;
```

The cache would be a simple:

```
if (isset($responses[$a][$b][$c]['status'])) {
     ... used cached value
} else {
     ... compute new value and store in cache
}
```

Though you might want some extra logic in there to expire older entries, other you'll end up sucking up memory until things die.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache the response from your daemon here are some options

1 - If on PHP < 5.5 , you can use apc's user cache

Here is how save some random piece of text (does not matter if its JSON or an object , you will be able to retrieve it fine)

```
    apc_add('cache_key',$save_this_var, TTL);
```

OR

```
     apc_store('cache_key',$save_this_var, TTL);
```

apc_add will not overwrite if you save something else with the exact same key ,    whereas apc_store will overwrite 
TTL is the time (in seconds) you want to cache the data for

Now you can retrieve the cache like so

```
     $my_cache = apc_fetch('cache_key');
```

$my_cache has the variable you saved earlier

2 - If you are using PHP 5.5 , then make use apc's user cache by adding the apcu module ,it works exactly like apc cache I explained above ,just a name change (apcu does not cache opcode whereas apc in PHP < 5.4 does)

3 -  If you are in a cloud or multiserver environment , you can use memcached as well , but if on single machine , i would go with apc or apcu